# JavaDoc, Top Level Documentation for the Project as a whole

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

I thought providing top level (Project level) Java Doc would be a straight forward thing to do, but I look around and I see an abundance of information on how to document packages, but nothing on how to document whole Java projects, so that the index page of the documentation contains a title and a project description, as well as all the packages in the project.

Lets say I have a project, in its src directory I have three packages each with various Java classes. Each class has JavaDoc and each Package alpha, beta, and delta has internally package-info.java to document each package: As follows. When I do this the index of the documentation has no title and just lists the packages. I would like a place to include a title and a project description, version information etc.

```
src:
======================
alpha
  package-info.Java
  Theta.Java
  Omega.Java

beta
  package-info.Java
  Gamma.java
  Epsilon.Java

delta
   package-info.java
   Kappa.java
   Iota.java
```

Is there a way to have top level Java Documentation for all three packages without placing all three packages inside an outermost package? Or is the outer most package the only way to do this and how Java expects project to be structured? For example:

```
src:
======================
my_proj:
  package-info.Java

  my_proj.alpha
    package-info.Java
    Theta.Java
    Omega.Java

  my_proj.beta
    package-info.Java
    Gamma.java
    Epsilon.Java

  my_proj.delta
    package-info.java
    Kappa.java
    Iota.java
```

Comment: I did a package back in 2005.   I'll see if I can dig it up.  Have you documented all of your classes and methods for at least one class?  Ultimately you will end up with a set of html files based on your .java files.  Also, learn about the Java manifest file.  That is very important.

Comment: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J9c_PackageClasspath.html#:~:text=CLASSPATH%20is%20an%20environment%20variable,used%20in%20a%20Java%20program.

Comment: This instruction is very important.  "To make a class as part of a package, you have to include the package statement as the first statement in the source file."

Comment: The files should have the same structure as the package fully qualified names.  So you should have a folder called my_proj and another for beta under myproj, and another for delta under my_proj, and so on.

Comment: @MacGyver Thank you for your timely response to my question. I am well aware of how to create classes in packages, and I do know about nesting packages. My question relates to documenting an entire project consisting of three different packages. I want a top level documentation to outline the entire project.

Comment: I'm not aware of a "project" being an actual entity (or term) of Java.  It is likely a term used by your IDE.  To confirm, you could track down the source code for javadoc.  What IDE are you using?  Java and Javadoc was probably developed way before modern IDEs that incorporate allow you to build Java projects.

Comment: Its more of a general question regardless of any specific IDE. I guess I use the term project to define a collection of related packages and class files that work together to define a software application when compiled. Its nothing more or less than that.

Comment: The answer to your question is likely not possible "out of the box" unless there is a Visual Studio Code extension for it (there are thousands).  Or a Visual Studio nuget package.  Visual Studio started using the term "project" for computer applications and all of the IDEs out there followed.  I'm sure Microsoft wasn't the first to use the term to group a collection of source code files and other objects into a single entity.  One thing to check are the IDEs that deal strictly with Java.  They might have built an extension for it.  Eclipse is a common one.  Jetbrains maybe.

Comment: Can I ask you a simple question here?  Are you asking so that you can easily document project version changes at the top level?  And when someone goes to a specific version, they see the executive summary (changes that occurred since the last release)?

Comment: I'm wanting to say what the project's title is, what the project does, why it exists. who its authors are and what the current version is.

Comment: The reason I ask is because programmers eventually make a distinction between building an application (project in IDE) and building a programming framework or API (in Java, this is called a package, in C#, this would be a DLL or library, in Python, this would be a module, etc..).  If you are truly building an application, then you should not grab files from a package.  You should include the package and call into it.  The reason a project exists is to separate the idea of a project (for an application) and the things to include in a project (like packages).  Likely why one does not exist.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you bud.  I think most programmers put this top level project information into source control (ie: SVN, GitHub, etc..) for an application or project.  Whenever you make a commit in Github, you can list what files need to change for that version and put the documentation in there.  What you are asking is an interesting question and challenging question, so it might not exist yet.

Comment: I may have an actual answer for you, or at least a lead.  Javadoc allows you to create the "standard doclet".  You can even customize the doclet to your own format!  I think this is what you want.  The author can go there.  And other custom things.

Comment: "To customize the output of the Javadoc tool, you need to write your own doclet that specifies the content and format of the output that you desire. If you want HTML output with roughly the same format as the default output, you can use the standard doclet as a starting point for creating your doclet."

Comment: While it is done often to have only one level of folder to a package, the java tutorial has often recommended to start with a package folder "com" or "net" and then another folder down then inside that second starts individual package folder sets with either subset folders and or classes. Web servers get awfully fussy if that naming scheme isn't found in jar packages.

Comment: This will get you started.  Just make sure to look at the version of Java you have installed.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html

Comment: Also, you can post a question here once you have a start.  Search existing questions for "custom doclet".  https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/domain/dev-community/category/java_apis?tags=javadoc-tool-developer-tool-apis&s=custom+doclet

Comment: Samuel Marchent, thanks that was just what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been a couple of days since I posted the question and I have worked out what I think is the proper way to do it in Java 1.9 and above. For Java versions <= 1.8 and below, I still do not have an answer and will welcome suggestions.

Firstly, it is the convention that projects themselves should be in a named package. By convention this looks like a URL in reverse, starting with the least specific thing and drilling down to the most specific project name. For example:

```
edu.myuni.mycourse.myname.my_proj2000
```

or for a business organization.

```
com.mycompany.myproj2000
```

What you would see in your project directory, if you created such a package name is a folder hierarchy such as the following. This is what an IDE would generate, but if you are doing this manually (without and IDE), you would have to create this yourself.

```
src/com/mycompany/myproj200/
```

So then your project packages, would then be created inside the myproj2000 directory as shown below. If we take a Java class such as **Theta** then it would be. c**om.mycompany.myproj2000/alpha/Theta.java**. This is what is known as a **fully qualified name**. This has the benefit of uniquely identifying your class in a large project where classes in different packages may have the same name.

So the directory structure  is therefore as follows with each package getting a **package-info.java** for documentation purposes, and the project as a whole getting **module-info.java** Below is the structure of the project, and below this is example of what the **package-info.java** and **module-info.java** would look like.

```
src:
======================
com.mycompany.myproj2000:
  module-info.java

  com.mycompany.myproj2000.alpha
    package-info.Java
    Theta.Java
    Omega.Java

  com.mycompany.myproj2000.beta
    package-info.Java
    Gamma.java
    Epsilon.Java

  com.mycompany.myproj2000.delta
    package-info.java
    Kappa.java
    Iota.java
```

Then within this project the package-info looks as follows where the documentation comes above the package documentation.

```
/**
*My documentation for my lovely alpha package, blah blah blah. It does blah blah.
* @Author Joe Bloggs
* @Version 1.02 Spring 2023
**/
package com.mucompany.myproj2000.apha;
```

The module-info.java looks similar.

```
/**
* This project does blah blah blah it was created for blah blah so that blah blah
* @Author Joe Bloggs
* @Version 1.02 Spring 2023
**/
module com.mycompany.myproj2000{
}
```

I suspect that before Java 1.9 when modules were introduced that the outer most package **com.mycompany.myproj2000** would also get a package-info.java, if anyone would confirm that I'd like to know.